# How can I customize ionic range

Tags: ionic-framework, range

I have the below ionic range in my html file. I tried finding to customize the css but no success. I want something like this[image: custom range]

```
                        <div class="item range">
                            <input type="range" name="volume">
                        </div>
```

Comment: i made half of it look on this http://codepen.io/edisonpappi/pen/ybMMxL

Comment: @Edison I get this by default.  Using ionic range class